# How to send an email to a senior editor?

Tags: paper-submission, editors, journal-workflow

We have sent a comment paper to Physical Review B, but the editor told us to extend this comment paper and convert it to a regular paper. But we have already written a regular paper and wanted to send it to Physical Review B after this comment paper. It's not possible to send this comment paper to another journal due to the laws. My supervisor isdisappointed and said nothing else about our regular paper.

I don't know who our editor was, for this reason I want to send an email to the senior editor of PRB and describe the situation and convince him to give us a chance again to resubmit our comment. How can do this? And who is the best choice to email to?

Comment: I don't understand, if you have already an extented paper that you want to publish, why not send this to the journal? Why do you feel you need to publish this comment separately from the paper, just to increase publication count? And why not simply reply to the email which you received from the journal to ask about the possibility to publish the comment?

Comment: No first we were writing our regular paper, and at that time we found another group have published a paper in PRB including mistake which was explainable using our model, so wrote a comment paper and described the mistake by a brief refer to our model.

Comment: But you could just include that comment in the extended paper?

Comment: No because our main paper is about 30 pages dedicated to explain the model, so we couldn't add correction for the mistake to it. However, I think it's a common way to correct another paper in the form of comment.

Comment: Then I suggest to respond to the email you received with exactly the information that you provided here and see how it goes

Comment: The problem is that my supervisor responded to the email, but said nothing about our main paper. Now he is disappointed and thinks that they don't care about this. So I want to try my chance and email senior editor of PRB myself.  But I have no idea who is the best choice to email to? Can you help me please?